# Can I put my dependencies and repositories in another file?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a requirement that some of my dependencies are in a separate file. How can I accomplish this? One of the samples on docs.gradle.org is:

```
List groovy = ["org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7@jar",
           "commons-cli:commons-cli:1.0@jar",
           "org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.6@jar"]
List hibernate = ['org.hibernate:hibernate:3.0.5@jar',
              'somegroup:someorg:1.0@jar']

dependencies {
    runtime groovy, hibernate
}
```

Something like this would work, but I'd also like to specify my repositories in the same file.

Edit:

The solution I came up with

`stuff.gradle`

```
repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username 'stuff'
            password 'stuff'
        }
        url 'stuff'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'things'
}
```

And in `build.gradle`

`apply from: 'path/to/stuff.gradle'`

After `dependencies`, though I'm not sure if it makes a difference. It was surprisingly simple. There were no changes to `build.gradle` apart from the apply statement, it still has the normal `repositories` and `dependencies` closures. Thanks to Opal for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

**lol.gradle:**

```
ext.repos = { mavenCentral(); mavenLocal() }

ext.groovy = [
          "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7@jar",
           "commons-cli:commons-cli:1.0@jar",
           "org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.6@jar",
           ]
ext.hibernate = [
          'org.hibernate:hibernate:3.0.5@jar',
          ]
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: 'lol.gradle'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories repos

dependencies {
  runtime groovy, hibernate
}
```

Since repositories can be kept as a list, the simplest way of keeping repositories with no workarounds is to use a closure. If you use a list to keep repositories as well it will fail with with method resolution error for both `mavenLocal` and `mavenCentral`.

If you prefer to keep repositories as a list however then the following piece of code can be used:

**lol.gradle**

```
ext.repos = ['mavenCentral', 'mavenLocal',]

ext.groovy = [
          "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7@jar",
           "commons-cli:commons-cli:1.0@jar",
           "org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.6@jar",
           ]
ext.hibernate = [
          'org.hibernate:hibernate:3.0.5@jar',
          ]
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: 'lol.gradle'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories { r ->
  repos.each { n -> r."$n"() }
}

dependencies {
  runtime groovy, hibernate
}
```

Comment: I might need to clarify my requirement. I want to keep some dependencies in build.gradle and add others from a different file.

Comment: I know the question and answer is pretty old, but still it's best I was able to find.. Does it still work this way? I declared my ext.repos same way in my repos.gradle, then tried to use it via apply from, but it throws error saying: ```> Could not get unknown property 'repos' ```

Comment: @shemekh which version do you use?